# Conversão de bases

Tags: python, numpy

Em um trabalho da faculdade nos foi exigido simular o funcionamento de uma memória RAM. O usuário pode ler ou escrever nas células dessa memória ou zera todas, sendo que cada uma armazena 8 bits. Essa parte já está feita, mas há algo que não consigo resolver. O usuário pode pedir o endereço de uma célula ou ler o conteúdo dela em binário ou em hexadecimal, de acordo com a escolha dele, mas estou com dificuldades em converter os elementos de cada célula (que já estão em binário) para hexadecimal.

O código está assim:

```
import numpy as np

celulas = np.array([(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)])
while True:
    operação = str(input('Ler[A], Escrever[B] ou Limpar[c]? Para terminar a aplicação[D]')).upper()
    if operação == 'A':
        endereço = int(input('Qual célula ler?'))
        base = int((input('Você quer ler em binário(1) ou em hexadecimal(2)?')))
        if base == 1:
            cels = [str(i) for i in celulas[endereço - 1]]
            print(''.join(cels))
    if operação == 'B':
        endereço = int(input('Qual célula escrever?'))
        cont = 0
        while cont <= 7:
            celulas[endereço-1][cont] = int(input('Digite 1 ou 0'))
            cont += 1
    if operação == 'C':
        cont = 0
        while cont <= 31:
            celulas[cont] = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
            cont += 1
    if operação == 'D':
        break
```

Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito mais fácil de obter uma representação hexadecimal é transformar o valor em questão em `bytes` e chamar a sua função `.hex()`.

Como você não está lidando na sua "memória" com números realmente binários, mas sim inteiros que assumem o valor 1 ou 0, temos que

1. Transformar os inteiros em uma string binária
2. Transformar a string binária em um inteiro
3. Transformar o inteiro em `bytes`
4. Aplicar a função `hex`

Podemos fazer isso assim:

```
base = int((input('Você quer ler em binário(1) ou em hexadecimal(2)?')))
if base == 1:
    cels = [str(i) for i in celulas[endereço - 1]]
    print(''.join(cels))
if base == 2:

    # Pegar a representação binária da célula (10111001)
    cels = [str(i) for i in celulas[endereço - 1]]
    representacao_binaria = ''.join(cels)

    # Converter representação binária em inteiro (indicando que nossa
    # string está em base 2, binária)
    inteiro = int(representacao_binaria, base=2)

    # Transformamos o inteiro em um byte, e pegamos sua representação
    # hexadecimal (ex. b9)
    representacao_hexadecimal = inteiro.to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder).hex()

    # Mudamos um pouco a apresentação (b9 -> 0xB9)
    print('0x' + representacao_hexadecimal.upper())
```

Comment: Perfeito, meu amigo, deu certo. Muito obrigado